# Please commit the pending task error while insertion. What to use please Guide

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, batch, schedulebatch

Master Object :- MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User__c

Detail Object :- MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c

**step 1)** Inserting in Master object (only 1 record i wanna insert that is simple Insert). Inserting into MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User__c (User's Name)
before the first insert statement i am calling facebook Graph API and retrieving the name of facebook user. Need to insert facebook user name in salesforce. 
**step 2)** Inserting in Detail Object (calling batch for inserting  more than 1 records.)
After inserting the name and ID in salesforce i want to insert facebook pages names and ID that are owned by that User.

**Both insertion is in single method on page load.**

**Throws error :- Please commit or rollback before calling out**

Is there anything i need to use ?? which is better approach ?

Please Find the code.

```
Http http =new Http();
HttpRequest req =new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,picture&access_token='+token);
req.setmethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);             
facebookuser objfacebookuser = new facebookuser(); // wrapper class
objfacebookuser=facebookuser.parse(res.getBody());
MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User__c objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User = new MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User__c();
objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User.MBT_SFFB__Facebook_ID__c = objfacebookuser.id; 
objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User.MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Name__c =objfacebookuser.name;
objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User.MBT_SFFB__Image__c = objfacebookuser.picture.data.url;
objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User.MBT_SFFB__Validated__c=true;
insert objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User;
Http http =new Http();
HttpRequest req =new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=accounts{picture,name}&access_token='+token);
req.setmethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);             
facebookpages objallfacebookpages = new facebookpages();
objallfacebookpages=facebookpages.parse(res.getBody());           
List<facebookpages.Data_Z> objallfacebookpageslist =  new  List<facebookpages.Data_Z>(); // wrapper class
objallfacebookpageslist = objallfacebookpages.accounts.data; 
addfbpagestosystem c = new  addfbpagestosystem(objfbpagestoinsert,objallfacebookpages.id); // batch Apex class
Database.executeBatch(c);
```

Code of batch apex:-

```
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> scope)
 {    

   for(facebookpages.Data_Z objfbpage :fbpages)
   {
       MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c objrecfbpage = new MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c(MBT_SFFB__Facebook_ID__c=id,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c=objfbpage.id,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_Name__c=objfbpage.name,MBT_SFFB__Image__c=objfbpage.picture.data.url,MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User_Relates_To_Page__c='wanna ID of first insertion');           
       objmtfbpage.add(objrecfbpage);
   }              
    insert objmtfbpage;      
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code snippet for better understanding? Are you doing any callout?

Comment: Please Find the Code above.

Comment: Yes, so the problem is you are doing an insert operation while the callout is made. In 1 transaction you cannot make DML operation when you're doing a callout.

Comment: What's the sequence of code execution, how it is been triggered from VF Page or some other triggering point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code, Removed the `DML insert operation` from between the `HTTP callout` and now it is been made after the `HTTP callout`.

```
List<MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User__c> insertList = new List<MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User__c>();
Http http =new Http();
HttpRequest req =new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,picture&access_token='+token);
req.setmethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);             
facebookuser objfacebookuser = new facebookuser(); // wrapper class
objfacebookuser=facebookuser.parse(res.getBody());
MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User__c objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User = new MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User__c();
objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User.MBT_SFFB__Facebook_ID__c = objfacebookuser.id; 
objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User.MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Name__c =objfacebookuser.name;
objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User.MBT_SFFB__Image__c = objfacebookuser.picture.data.url;
objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User.MBT_SFFB__Validated__c=true;
//Add into the list to insert it later after the callout is made
insertList.add(objMBT_SFFB_Facebook_User);
Http http =new Http();
HttpRequest req =new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=accounts{picture,name}&access_token='+token);
req.setmethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);             
facebookpages objallfacebookpages = new facebookpages();
//Insert DML is made after the HTTP Callout
insert insertList;
objallfacebookpages=facebookpages.parse(res.getBody());           
List<facebookpages.Data_Z> objallfacebookpageslist =  new  List<facebookpages.Data_Z>(); // wrapper class
objallfacebookpageslist = objallfacebookpages.accounts.data; 
addfbpagestosystem c = new  addfbpagestosystem(objfbpagestoinsert,objallfacebookpages.id); // batch Apex class
Database.executeBatch(c);
```